# How to make website readonly that link from certain websites. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a website where a user logs in, can see his information and edit it. There is also another website, something like a site only for admins, where if I click a link it redirects me to the first website, logged in as that user but I can only read his information not edit it. I am having trouble finding out how to make website 1 both readable only and read/writeable.

I am doing this in Asp.NET mvc using C#.

Comment: This is some serious big brother stuff. How about a flag on the session indicating if the user is being "puppeteered" by the admin.

Comment: @screenmutt Big Brother by viewing a user's profile? I can see yours without editing it....

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop It sounds from the question that the user has a private profile where he can see his "information". It does not say what information is being viewed. Also, if the admin must be "logged in" as the user, there is apparently some assumption of privacy with this information.

Comment: @screenmutt It also doesn't actually say the only access to the user profile is via the admin site. The admin site merely has a redirect to the original. Even if it were the case, I could see this being totally non-nefarious. Perhaps it has sensitive data that an employer would already know but a coworker would not.

Comment: Even so, what's the difference between being "logged in" as the user, vs an admin portal, vs an admin doing a query in the database? The privacy implication is in who has access to the data, not how the admin views it (assuming of course the way they view it doesn't introduce vulnerabilities).

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you're asking. I think the principle you try to describe is a special form of "impersonation", where the admin account can "impersonate" a regular user up till a certain level (i.e. use the site as being that user, without being able to perform actions as that user, like posting messages or whatever it is the site does). If you're asking how to implement that, that's too broad. It all depends on how your site is set up and can't really be implemented as an afterthought.

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to check for authorization in the Razor view.

Psuedocode:

```
@if(User.IsAuthorizedForEdit()
{
    @*your edit view code*@
}
else
{
    @*your readonly view code*@
}
```

This does make for some bloaty Razor. The other (arguably, better) alternative is to direct them to the appropriate view in your controller based on user.

Handy-wavy psuedocode to give you an idea:

```
public ActionResult ViewProfile(int profileId)
{
    var user = GetCurrentUser();//without looking at your code, I can't infer this piece.
    var profile = GetProfile(profileId);
    if(IsAuthorizedToEdit(user, profileId)
    {
        return View("edit", profile);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("view", profile);
    }
}
```

In theory, you already have a read-only view and an edit view, so the latter would be more reusable.